# Git Hub page loads readme

Tags: github, github-pages, readme

My GitHub repos works the same with this but this one isn't working. It only loads the readme not my project and I check my default browser and my code works on google chrome and everything is at root

my repo link https://github.com/Alais555/YogurtBootstrap

link that suppose to be my project https://alais555.github.io/YogurtBootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

never mine there was typo for index it was .index.html not index.html. My bad ahaha goes to show check root files and folders to make sure there spelled correctly.